# Combining many greps in a single grep call

Tags: grep

I've a script where I've to check if a process is running by its name and I'm doing it using `ps` and `grep`. The problem is that I've to grep many things to avoid to find false positive.

By now, I've a `grep` chain that looks as follow:

`ps -ef | grep -i $process_name | grep -i perl | grep -v do_all | grep -v grep`

Four `grep`s. Three of them are there to avoid false positive.

I would like to know if there's a way to avoid such 'piping chain' and use a single `grep` to achieve the same result.

Though some of you could answer that there are cleaner way to find out if a process exists, I would like the same to have an answer to this question, just to better understand the usage of the `grep` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no real reason to avoid chaining them, is there?

If you really wanted to you could combine them with | in egrep:

```
ps -ef | egrep -i "$process_name|perl" |  egrep -v 'do_all|grep'
```

Comment: The reason is mainly esthetically. However, I think that if exists a method to call it once, it would be less expensive than call it multiple times, is it wrong?

Comment: @Zagorax But if this is not a bottleneck in your application then efficiency is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `GNU awk`:

```
ps -ef | awk -v process="$process_name" 'BEGIN { IGNORECASE=1 } $0 ~ process && /perl/ && !/do_all/'
```